# Convert LaTeX fonts to TTF fonts for use in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: fonts

Is there a way to convert LaTeX fonts like BeraSans, URWPalladioL to ttf fonts that can be used in Adobe Illustrator?

Thanks.

Comment: They're type 1 fonts, you just have to install them on your system. May I recall type 1 font  format was defined by Adobe? Also,  there are clones of these fonts in opentype format, which is much more precise for printing than true type.

Comment: @Bernard, Thanks for your comment.  I see for example that in the fonts folder in ...\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\afm\bera, the fonts have an extension afm.gz.  Can I just put these files into the Windows font directory or the directory that Illustrator looks for the fonts?

Comment: You'll also need to install the .pfb files. Not sure whether you'll have to unzip the .afm files, and ask to *install* them.

Comment: Actually, under Windows, you'll have to unzip the .afm.gz files, then convert the resulting .afm  to .pfm to be able to install the font. There exists a free application called `afmtopfm` that can do that.

Comment: BeraSans should be a type1 version of Bitstream Vera Sans so you should be able to get this one in TTF.

Comment: @Bernard Do you have a link?

Comment: Many of these fonts have since been extended or whatever and those versions are frequently available in truetype or opentype format. You might want to look into those before converting the originals. Some of the TeX Gyre fonts are derived from URW fonts, if I'm remembering correctly.

Comment: @cfr: Here you are: (http://www.proximasoftware.com/afmtopfm/)

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. That's not what I was thinking of. But it will hopefully be of use to the OP!